# Jenkins pipeline leaves conan.tmpxxxxx dirs under workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, conan

Background, we are just starting to use conan and want to integrate it with Jenkins pipeline builds, which are also new to us.

I have a simple pipeline job that iterates over a yaml file to discover the components used in a product, it then calls another pipeline, UploadRecipe, that downloads the components source, finds the recipes and uploads them to the relevant repo in artifactory

But, it leaves behind a whole bunch of conan.tmp dirs in workspace/UploadRecipe@tmp

```
$ pwd /jenkins_conan/workspace/UploadRecipe@tmp 
$ ls -1
conan.tmp1453946246097996081
conan.tmp2037444640117259875
conan.tmp3926464088111486375
conan.tmp7293377119892400567
conan.tmp868991149159211380
```

The pipeline didn't fail, but they never get cleaned up, it also happens in other conan related pipelines we use to generate large iso files that consume GB's, but the Upload recipe example is much simpler to explain and shows the same behaviour.

Is there something wrong in my pipeline groovy script ?

i.e. is there some command I should have called to tidy up ?

```
properties([parameters([string(description: 'Name/Version', name: 'name_version', defaultValue: 'base/1.0.2'),
                        string(description: 'User/Channel', name: 'user_channel', defaultValue: 'release/stable'),
                        string(description: 'SVN repository branch', name: 'svn_repo_branch', defaultValue: 'tags/CONAN_REL_1.0.2'),
                        string(description: 'SVN repository url', name: 'svn_repo_url', defaultValue: 'svn+ssh://$USER@svnserver/svncmake/base/'),
                        string(description: 'Artifactory', name: 'artifactory', defaultValue: 'my-artifactory'),
                        string(description: 'Upload repo', name: 'uploadRepo', defaultValue: 'stable-release')
                       ])])

node('buildserver') {
    withEnv(['PATH+LOCAL_BIN=/xxxxx/release/.virtualenvs/jfrog/bin']) {
        currentBuild.displayName = params.name_version + "@" + params.user_channel
        def server
        def client
        def uploadRepo
        def mysvncreds = 'creds-for-svn'
        def SVN_repo_url

        deleteDir()

        stage("Configure/Get recipe"){

            server = Artifactory.server params.artifactory
            client = Artifactory.newConanClient()

            uploadRepo = client.remote.add server: server, repo: params.uploadRepo

            dir("_comp_repo"){
                SVN_repo_url = params.svn_repo_url + params.svn_repo_branch
                checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', locations: [[credentialsId: mysvncreds, depthOption: 'files', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: SVN_repo_url ]]])
            }
        }

        stage("Export recipe"){
            dir("_comp_repo"){
                myrecipes = ['conanfile.py', 'conanfile_policy.py', 'conanfile_rpm.py']

                for(int i = 0; i < myrecipes.size(); i++) 
                { 
                    def thisrecipe = myrecipes[i]
                    if (fileExists(thisrecipe)) {
                        mycommand = "export ./" + thisrecipe + " "  + params.user_channel
                        client.run(command: mycommand )
                    } else {
                        echo thisrecipe
                    }
                }
                client.run(command: "search" )
            }
        }

        stage("Upload recipe to Artifactory"){
            def name_version = params.name_version
            string myname = name_version.split("/")[0]
            string myversion = name_version.split("/")[1]
            String command = "upload ${myname}*/*@${params.user_channel} -r ${uploadRepo} --all --confirm --retry 3 --retry-wait 10"

            client.run(command: command)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/2690. They could be the temporary directories for the conan cache, but not 100% sure how the plugin works with respect to this.

Answer (score 0):

do it in bash with find and remove

```
find /jenkins_conan/workspace/UploadRecipe@tmp -type f -name 'conan.tmp*' -exec rm -v {} \;
```

or try to add this to your pipeline

```
node('yournode') {
     ..
    stage 'removing cache files'
    def ws = pwd()
    def file = ws + '/conan.tmp*'
    sh 'rm ' + file + ' -rf' 
}
```

Comment: yep thats my fallback (but they are dirs not files so would need -type d I think), but would prefer to understand why it's happening. Wanted to raise an issue on their github page but couldn't see where to do it ? https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin